# wpautop add closing p tag when it should not

Tags: wordpress

WordPress 5.9.3

By adding the code below to functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
        error_log( wpautop('<div>
    <div>
        <h3>Let`s Debug</h3>
    </div>
</div>') );
    }
);
```

The output will look like below

```
[12-Apr-2022 04:37:11 UTC] <div>
<div>
<h3>Let`s Debug</h3>
</p></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it adds the closing p tag right after **h3**.

Appreciate it if someone can report this issue to WordPress or if another solution can be provided.

I can simply remove the tabs character and the issue will be solved.

wpautop is used not because I wanted to, but it is included in the **the_content** filter.

I can not remove wpautop from the filter because I am using a hook in priority 11 and wpautop is at 10.

I can remove the filter, apply the filter, then add the filter again but it will call the filter twice which is not quite optimized.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "extra" whitespace before your closing div after the closing heading tag like below:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
        error_log( wpautop('<div>
    <div>
        <h3>Let`s Debug</h3>
</div>
</div>') );
    }
);
```

this works too:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
        error_log( wpautop('<div>
    <div>
        <h3>Let`s Debug</h3></div>
</div>') );
    }
);
```